# service promise not resolving with karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a `service factory` that connects and interacts with an `api` for data. Here is the service:

```
angular.module('dbRequest', [])
  .factory('Request', ['$http', 'localConfig', function($http, localConfig){
    return {
      getDataRevision: function(){
        return $http({
          url: localConfig.dbDataUrl,
          method: "GET",
          crossDomain: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Taking cues from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991003/mock-angular-service-promise-in-a-karma-jasmine-test), This is how I am testing the method:

```
describe('Service: Request', function () {
  var $scope, srvMock, $q, lc, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('webApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, Request, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, localConfig){
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    srvMock = Request;
    $q = _$q_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    lc = localConfig;

    $httpBackend.expect('GET', lc.dbDataUrl);

    $httpBackend.when('GET', lc.dbDataUrl).respond({
      success: ["d1","d2", "d3"]
    });
  }));

  it('should return a promise', function(){
    expect(srvMock.getDataRevision().then).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should resolve with data', function(){
    var data;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promise = deferred.promise;

    promise.then(function(res){
      data = res.success;
    });

    srvMock.getDataRevision().then(function(res){
      deferred.resolve(res);
    });

    $scope.$digest();

    expect(data).toEqual(["d1","d2", "d3"]);
  })
});
```

`should return a promise` passes, but the next `should resolve with data` fails with this error:

```
Expected undefined to equal [ 'd1', 'd2', 'd3' ].
```

However, the `service` method `getDataRevision` is getting called, but not getting resolved by the mock promise in the test. How do I make the correction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are expecting mocked data to be there in `data` variable without flushing `httpRequest`s, but that won't happen till you `flush` all the `httpRequest`s. What `$httpBackend.flush()` does is, it returns mock data to that particular request that you have did using `$httpBackend.when('GET', lc.dbDataUrl).respond`.

Additionally you don't need to create extra promise which would be an overhead. Instead of having custom promise you could have utilize service function returned promise itself like below.

**Code**

```
it('should resolve with data', function(){
    var data;

    srvMock.getDataRevision().then(function(res){
      data = res.success;
    });

    $scope.$digest();
    $httpBackend.flush(); //making sure mocked response has been return
    //after .then evaluation only below code will get called.
    expect(data).toEqual(["d1","d2", "d3"]);
})
```

Comment: solution works perfectly! However, do you mind explaining how the test case is executed? As `httpbackend success` response will always be equal to the `expected data`? In other words, how (am I/should I) testing the `response` returned from service `promise`?