# How to test an AngularJS service which depends on a previous test passing?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a passing test for an AngularJS 1.5.9 service and I want to test another function call on the same service, in a separate it(). The problem is that the result of the second service function depends on the passing result of the first service call; As the service is re-instantiated for each it() the success result of the first test is effectively lost.

My question is based on [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039953/cannot-read-property-of-undefined-in-angular-karma-test/46050978#46050978) answer.

What I think I would like to do is something like this, where the service function tested in the first test is used normally in the second test:

```
describe('user-service', function () {
    var $httpBackend, $q, $rootScope;
    var mockUserData = { "d": { "firstName": "Matt", "lastName": "Lenny" };
    var mockCatalogueData = { "d": { "title": "A Feast of Crows" };

    beforeEach(module('users'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_,_$q_,_$rootScope_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

        $httpBackend.when('GET', /(.*)\/user\/api/).respond(200, mockUserData);
        $httpBackend.when('GET', /(.*)\/cat\/api/).respond(200, mockCatalogueData);
    }));

    it('should return the user object', inject(function (userService) {
        var user;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        promise.then(function (response) {
            user = response;
        });

        userService.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(user).toEqual(mockUserData.d);
    }));

    it('should return the catalogue object', inject(function (userService) {
        var catalogue;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        promise.then(function (response) {
            catalogue = response;
        });

        userService.getUserInfo(); // populates internal userService data

        userService.getCatalogueInfo().then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(user).toEqual(mockCatalogueData.d);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this works, though I'm not entirely sure if it is the correct and proper way to perform the test:

```
describe('user-service', function () {
    var $httpBackend, $q, $rootScope;
    var mockUserData = { "d": { "firstName": "Matt", "lastName": "Lenny" };
    var mockCatalogueData = { "d": { "title": "A Feast of Crows" };

    beforeEach(module('users'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_,_$q_,_$rootScope_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

        $httpBackend.when('GET', /(.*)\/user\/api/).respond(200, mockUserData);
        $httpBackend.when('GET', /(.*)\/cat\/api/).respond(200, mockCatalogueData);
    }));

    it('should return the user object', inject(function (userService) {
        var user;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        promise.then(function (response) {
            user = response;
        });

        userService.getUserInfo().then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(user).toEqual(mockUserData.d);
    }));

    it('should return the catalogue object', inject(function (userService) {
        var catalogue;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        userService.getUserInfo().then(function() { // populates internal userService data
            promise.then(function (response) {
                catalogue = response;
            });

            userService.getCatalogueInfo().then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });
        });


        $rootScope.$digest();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(user).toEqual(mockCatalogueData.d);
    }));
});
```